# Why the polynomial $x^{p+1}=y$ has exactly $p+1$ solutions in $F_{p^2}^*$ for $y \in F_p^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In some combinatorics book I found the following remarks about multiplicative groups of finite fields:
Let p be an odd prime number and $q=p^2$. Then $F_p^*$ can be identified with the elements $x$ of $F_q^*$ that satisfy $x^{p-1}=1$.
Furthermore, for fixed $y \in F_p^*$ the polynomial $y=x^{p+1}$ has exactly p+1 solutions in $F_q^*$.

I understand that the key to all of these is the decomposition $q-1=(p+1)(p-1)$. Nevertheless one question still remains:
Why the mentioned polynomial has exactly $p+1$ solutions?
I know that the zeros of $x^{q-1}-1$ are exactly the elements of $F_q^*$, but I can't finish the argument.

Comment: $F_q^*$ is cyclic

Comment: Unfortunately I know that and still don't get it.

Comment: To be precise I don't get why a solution exists. The rest is clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplicative group of $F_{p^2}-\{0\}$ is cyclic (of order $p^2-1$, of course), which is a basic fact in field theory.
Moreover, under the inclusion $\tau: F_{p}\to F_{p^2}$, the members of $\tau(F_p)$ are characterized by
\begin{equation*}
\tau(F_p)=\{x\in F_{p^2}: x^p=x\}.
\end{equation*}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
\tau(F_p-\{0\})= \{x\in F_{p^2}: x^{p-1}=1\}.
\end{equation*}

Let $a\in F_{p^2}-\{0\}$ generate the cyclic group $(F_{p^2}-\{0\},\cdot)$.
If $m$ is an integer s.t. $0\le m< p^2-1$, then $y=a^m\in \tau(F_p-\{0\})$ iff $a^{m(p-1)}=1$,
iff $m(p-1)$ is a multiple of $p^2-1$, iff $m=(p+1)k$ for some $0\le k< p+1$.

Now we study the equation $x^{p+1}=y(=a^m=a^{(p+1)k})$.
Assume $x=a^l$ ($0\le l< p^2-1$). For $a^{l(p+1)}=x^{p+1}=a^{(p+1)k}$ to hold, it is necessary and sufficient that
$(p+1)l-(p+1)k$ is a multiple of $p^2-1$, and is therefore equivalent to $l-k$ is a multiple of $p-1$, or, $l=(p-1)N+k$ for some $k$.
In $\{0,1,\cdots,p^2-2\}$, there are exactly $p+1$ elements of the form $(p-1)N+k$, one in each row:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cccc}
 (p-1)\cdot 0=0 & 1 & \cdots & p-2 \\ 
 (p-1)\cdot 1=p-1 & p & \cdots & 2p-3 \\ 
 \cdots &  &  &  \\ 
 (p-1)\cdot p=p^2-p & p^2-p+1 &  & p^2-2
\end{array}.\end{equation*}
Since, if $l_1,l_2\in \{0,1,\cdots,p^2-2\}$ and $l_1\ne l_2$, then $a^{l_1}\ne a^{l_2}$,
therefore $x^{p+1}=y$ has exactly $p+1$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't "$l-k$ is a multiple of $p-1$" mean that $l=(p\color{red}-1)N+k$  for some $k$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks. This is a typo, and the answer is still valid.

Comment: Did you mean there are exactly $p+1$ elements?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

Define $\phi: F_q^\times \to F_q^\times$ by $\phi(x)=x^{p+1}$. This is a group homomorphism.

Then $\phi(x)^{p-1}=x^{(p+1)(p-1)}=x^{q-1}=1$ and so $\operatorname{im}{\phi} \subseteq \{ x \in F_q^\times : x^{p-1} =1 \}$. Therefore, $|\operatorname{im}{\phi}| \le p-1$.

On the other hand, $\ker \phi = \{ x \in F_q^\times : x^{p+1} =1 \}$ and so $|\ker \phi| \le p+1$. Therefore, $|\operatorname{im}{\phi}| \ge p-1$ because $|\operatorname{im}{\phi}|\cdot |\ker \phi| = |F_q^\times|$.

Thus, $|\operatorname{im}{\phi}| = p-1$ and so $\operatorname{im}{\phi} = \{ x \in F_q^\times : x^{p-1} =1 \} = F_p^\times$.

Finally, $|\ker \phi| = p+1$, and we are done.

This proof does not use that $F_q^\times$ is cyclic. It uses only that polynomials of degree $d$ have at most $d$ roots in a field and that $g^n=1$ in every group of order $n$.

Comment: The proof works for every $q=p^e$. Just write $q-1=(p-1)m$ to conclude that $y=x^m$ has exactly $m$ solutions for every $y \in  F_p^\times$.

Comment: I'm glad you appreciated it.  Sorry if I'm being pedantic, but can you explain how to go from  |ker$\phi$|$=p+1$ (i.e., $x^{p+1}=1$ has $p+1$ solutions) to $x^{p+1}=y$ has $p+1$ solutions?  (I guess you know that $x^{p+1}=y$ has a solution since $y\in F_p^\times=$ im$\phi$, and then you can multiply that solution by the $p+1$ solutions of $x^{p+1}=1$ to get the $p+1$ solutions to $x^{p+1}=y$?)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, exactly: if $b = \phi(a)$, then $\phi^{-1}(b)=a \ker \phi$, for every group homomorphism $\phi$.