Surjective polynomial map from $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ to $\mathbb{F}_q$
Let $f \colon \mathbb{F}_{q^2} \to \mathbb{F}_q$ be a surjective polynomial map such that  $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^r (x - \alpha_i) \in \mathbb{F}_{q^2}[x]$ is a polynomial where $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_r \in \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ are distinct elements in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$.
For instance, the trace map $\text{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^2} / \mathbb{F}_{q}} \colon \mathbb{F}_{q^2} \to \mathbb{F}_{q}$ is a such map. More generally, a separable linearized map $f(x)=a_n x^{q^n}+a_{n-1}x^{q^{n-1}}+ \cdots + a_0x$ is also such a map.
My question: Are linearized polynomials the only ones with this property? Or are these possible maps related to the linearized ones?
Thanks in advance.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887827/why-the-polynomial-xp1-y-has-exactly-p1-solutions-in-f-p2-for-y

@lhf Thanks. My question is related to that linked, but $f(x)=x^{q+1}$ has a multiple zero. I would like to know the case that $f(x)$ has no repeated root.

You can also use $f(x)=x^{q+1}-1$. It is onto, because the relative norm map $N(x)=x^{q+1}$ is. And its roots are simple! $f(x)=x^{q+1}-a$ will work whenever $a\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$.

On the other hand, at least one of the elements of the elements of the smaller field must appear as a value at least $q$ times. Therefore $\deg f(x)\ge q$.
